# connecting a multi value parameter to subreports

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, parameter-passing, crystal-reports-xi, subreports

I have a crystal xi report with a main report and lots of subreports.

I have linked all the sub reports to 2 parameters which works perfectly well for individual matches of criteria, however I now need to be able to chose multiple criteria for one of the parameters which I can set up but it just doesn't pass the details to the subreports.

This is what I have currently in my main report record selection

```
{Communication.Comm_Status} = "Complete" and
isnull ({Communication.Comm_Deleted}) and
{Communication.Comm_Action} = "PhoneOut" and
{Communication.comm_Result} in ["0", "1", "2"] and
not ({Communication.Comm_UpdatedBy} in [30, 33, 59]) and
{Communication.Comm_DateTime} in LastFullWeek and
{Territories.Terr_Caption} = {?Client} and
{Company.comp_campaign} = {?Campaign}
```

and this is what I have in my subreports record selection

```
isnull ({Communication.Comm_Deleted}) and
{Communication.Comm_Status} = "Complete" and
{Territories.Terr_Caption} = {?Pm-Territories.Terr_Caption} and
{Territories.Terr_Caption} = {?Pm-Territories.Terr_Caption} and
{Communication.comm_Result} in ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"] and
not ({Communication.Comm_UpdatedBy} in [30, 33, 59]) and
{Communication.Comm_DateTime} in LastFullWeek and
{Company.comp_campaign} = {?Pm-Company.comp_campaign}
```

I suppose what I would ideally like is  '=' parameter1 and 'contains' in parameter2

I have tried to search for resolutions, but I don't know what terms I should be looking for join; multi-value parameter or something else?

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure in your example which paramter is which, but you could do something like:

```
({tableName.tableField} = {?parameter1} AND
InStr({tableName.tableField}, {?parameter2}) > 0)
```

That would make sure that your field is equal to parameter 1 and that parameter 2 is contained in the field. You may need to convert your field to a string if it is a different data type.

EDIT:

Sorry, I guess I've not been paying 100% attention to the question. If you have a multi value parameter, then you have to treat it like an array (that's why you got the error with my original formula). In order to loop through the array, you need to create a formula like so:

```
 WhilePrintingRecords;
 numbervar x := 1;
 numbervar y := 0;

 while x <= ubound({?Campaign})

 do
 (if instr({Company.comp_campaign},{?Campaign}[x],1) > 0
 then y := y + 1;
 x := x + 1);

 y
```

EDIT:

```
 WhilePrintingRecords;
 stringvar array campaign := {?Campaign};
 numbervar x := 1;
 numbervar y := 0;

 for x := 1 to ubound(campaign)
 do
 (if instr({Company.comp_campaign},{?Campaign}[x],1) > 0
 then y := y + 1;
 x := x + 1);
 y
```

Then in your record select you need to check for the formula > 0.

Comment: Hi!  thanks for this, it could work

I added as above and get 'This array must be subscripted. For example: Array [i]'

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the full statement please?

Comment: {Communication.Comm_Status} = "Complete" and
isnull ({Communication.Comm_Deleted}) and
{Communication.Comm_Action} = "PhoneOut" and
{Communication.comm_Result} in ["0", "1", "2"] and
not ({Communication.Comm_UpdatedBy} in [30, 33, 59]) and
{Communication.Comm_DateTime} in LastFullWeek and

({Territories.Terr_Caption} = {?Client} AND
InStr({Company.comp_campaign}, {?Campaign}) > 0)

When the error shows it highlights {?Campaign}

Comment: Can you give me an example for a value of {Company.comp_campaign}? And what data type and values do you have for {?Campaign}? I just did a sample on my system and the formula I gave you in my answer works fine. Try just the formula I gave you with nothing else in the Record Select and see if you get an error. Then add one line at a time and see where you get the error.

Comment: hi the values in {Company.comp_campaign}? are 2 or 3 digit values of which there can be 1 or more selections, each separated by a comma like:

,142,102,228,
,142,
,346,228,

I need to exclude records which contain ,346, whether its a single value or contained with other values.

does that make sense?

Comment: That makes sense. So is {Company.comp_campaign} a number field or a string field? And what about {?Campaign}? Number or string? The formula works if both fields are strings. Have you tried only the formula in your record select without anything else?

Comment: Ok have tried that and get error " A Variable cannot be redeclared with a different type" 

and highlights numbervar x   in the formula....

really appreciate your help on this!

Comment: I really don't know. You could leave the line x := x + 1 out, but then it will only look at the first value of the array and you could actually just use the first formula like this ({tableName.tableField} = {?parameter1} AND
InStr({tableName.tableField}, {?parameter2}[1]) > 0)
The error doesn't make any sense since x is the index of the array and just gets incremented until it has reached the maximum. I'm going to slightly alter the formual, see the edit in my original answer.